# How can I compile first 2 pages of 24 pages in a Latex document?

Tags: pdf, latex, compilation

My work has over 24 pages in Latex. I need only the abstract and introduction in pdf. How can you compile only the first two pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd just make a new file with only the abstract and introduction and compile that.

Actually, if this is not just a one-time thing, I'd use three files:

`absintro.tex`:

```
\begin{abstract}
  ...
\end{abstract}
...introduction...
```

`onlyabsintro.tex`:

```
...
\begin{document}
    \include{absintro.tex}
\end{document}
```

`fullreport.tex`:

```
...
\begin{document}
   \include{absintro.tex}
   ...other stuff...
\end{document}
```

(Obviously the filenames can be whatever you want, this just shows the structure) You can compile `onlyabsintro.tex` to get only the abstract and introduction, or `fullreport.tex` to get the whole thing.

Comment: Good advice here. There is also much to be said for using a makefile (or similar build support mechanism) to manage all this for you.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [David's good advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757689/how-can-i-compile-first-2-pages-of-24-pages-in-a-latex-document/757728#757728), you could simple compile the whole thing, then extract the pages you want from the finished product. This might be the easiest approach for a one time task.

If you compile to PDF, consider using [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/), which would let you use a command like:

```
pdftk A=one.pdf cat A1-2 output intro.pdf
```

Comment: This could be a better answer if it gave a quick demonstration of how to extract the first couple of pages from the finished product.

Comment: I now understand the benefit of this answer. I have 777 pages in my current document. This solution rocks if you have more than 24 pages.

Answer (score 3):

There is a package `pagesel` that does exactly this. Say you have the following document

```latex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[1, 2]{pagesel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\centerline{page 1}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\centerline{page 2}
\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\centerline{page 3}
\lipsum[3]
\newpage
\centerline{page 4}
\lipsum[4]
\newpage
\centerline{page 5}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

`\usepackage[1, 2]{pagesel}` will tell LaTeX to only compile first and second pages (`lipsum` only generates random text and is not necessary).